# Angular 2 RC1 browser adapter error

Tags: angular

after upgradnidg my angular2 beta app to the RC1 version, I got the following error in my browser console log:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
browser_adapter.ts:78 EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ browser_adapter.ts:89ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:53(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:345ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216NgZoneImpl.runInner @ ng_zone_impl.ts:99NgZone.run @ ng_zone.ts:210ApplicationRef_.run @ application_ref.ts:335ApplicationRef_.bootstrap @ application_ref.ts:357(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:105ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:56ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
browser_adapter.ts:78 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Router!BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:65(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:345ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216NgZoneImpl.runInner @ ng_zone_impl.ts:99NgZone.run @ ng_zone.ts:210ApplicationRef_.run @ application_ref.ts:335ApplicationRef_.bootstrap @ application_ref.ts:357(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:105ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:56ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
browser_adapter.ts:78 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:69(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:345ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216NgZoneImpl.runInner @ ng_zone_impl.ts:99NgZone.run @ ng_zone.ts:210ApplicationRef_.run @ application_ref.ts:335ApplicationRef_.bootstrap @ application_ref.ts:357(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:105ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:56ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
browser_adapter.ts:78 Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (exceptions.ts:14)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (reflective_exceptions.ts:53)
    at new NoProviderError (reflective_exceptions.ts:85)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (reflective_injector.ts:844)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.ts:873)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.ts:835)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.ts:632)
    at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (AppComponent_Host.template.js:15)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.create (view.ts:110)
    at DebugAppView.create (view.ts:315)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:70(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:345ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216NgZoneImpl.runInner @ ng_zone_impl.ts:99NgZone.run @ ng_zone.ts:210ApplicationRef_.run @ application_ref.ts:335ApplicationRef_.bootstrap @ application_ref.ts:357(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:105ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:56ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
browser_adapter.ts:78 ERROR CONTEXT:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:74(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:345ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216NgZoneImpl.runInner @ ng_zone_impl.ts:99NgZone.run @ ng_zone.ts:210ApplicationRef_.run @ application_ref.ts:335ApplicationRef_.bootstrap @ application_ref.ts:357(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:105ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:56ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
browser_adapter.ts:78 DebugContext {_view: _View_AppComponent_Host0, _nodeIndex: 0, _tplRow: 0, _tplCol: 0}BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:75(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:345ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216NgZoneImpl.runInner @ ng_zone_impl.ts:99NgZone.run @ ng_zone.ts:210ApplicationRef_.run @ application_ref.ts:335ApplicationRef_.bootstrap @ application_ref.ts:357(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:105ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:56ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
browser_adapter.ts:88 EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
browser_adapter.ts:78 EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ browser_adapter.ts:89ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:53(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:341ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:56ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
browser_adapter.ts:78 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Router!BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:65(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:341ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:56ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
browser_adapter.ts:78 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:69(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:341ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:56ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
browser_adapter.ts:78 Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (exceptions.ts:14)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (reflective_exceptions.ts:53)
    at new NoProviderError (reflective_exceptions.ts:85)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (reflective_injector.ts:844)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.ts:873)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.ts:835)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.ts:632)
    at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (AppComponent_Host.template.js:15)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.create (view.ts:110)
    at DebugAppView.create (view.ts:315)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:70(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:341ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:56ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
browser_adapter.ts:78 ERROR CONTEXT:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:74(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:341ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:56ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
browser_adapter.ts:78 DebugContext {_view: _View_AppComponent_Host0, _nodeIndex: 0, _tplRow: 0, _tplCol: 0}BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:75(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:341ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.ts:67ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.ts:56ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
browser_adapter.ts:88 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Router!
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/exceptions.js:17:23)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:39:16)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:75:16)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:776:19)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:804:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:767:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:576:21)
    at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (AppComponent_Host.template.js:15:70)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.create (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:66:21)
    at DebugAppView.create (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:259:44)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]
browser_adapter.ts:78 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Router!
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/exceptions.js:17:23)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:39:16)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:75:16)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:776:19)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:804:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:767:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:576:21)
    at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (AppComponent_Host.template.js:15:70)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.create (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:66:21)
    at DebugAppView.create (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:259:44)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ browser_adapter.ts:89ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:53(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:304schedulerFn @ async.ts:131SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext @ Subject.ts:154Subject._next @ Subject.ts:144Subject.next @ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit @ async.ts:117NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError @ ng_zone.ts:138NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.ts:90ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233_loop_1 @ zone.js:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
browser_adapter.ts:78 STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:56(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:304schedulerFn @ async.ts:131SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext @ Subject.ts:154Subject._next @ Subject.ts:144Subject.next @ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit @ async.ts:117NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError @ ng_zone.ts:138NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.ts:90ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233_loop_1 @ zone.js:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
browser_adapter.ts:78 Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Router!
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/exceptions.js:17:23)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:39:16)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:75:16)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:776:19)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:804:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:767:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:576:21)
    at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (AppComponent_Host.template.js:15:70)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.create (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:66:21)
    at DebugAppView.create (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:259:44)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:538:32)
    at PromiseCompleter.reject (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:515:14)
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.js:295:35)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:323:29)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone_impl.js:45:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:322:35)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:216:44)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:571:58
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone_impl.js:36:41)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:57(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:304schedulerFn @ async.ts:131SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext @ Subject.ts:154Subject._next @ Subject.ts:144Subject.next @ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit @ async.ts:117NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError @ ng_zone.ts:138NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.ts:90ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233_loop_1 @ zone.js:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Router!
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/exceptions.js:17:23)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:39:16)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:75:16)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:776:19)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:804:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:767:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:576:21)
    at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (AppComponent_Host.template.js:15:70)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.create (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:66:21)
    at DebugAppView.create (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:259:44)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object] ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ViewWrappedException {_wrapperMessage: "Error in :0:0", _originalException: NoProviderError, _originalStack: "Error: DI Exception↵    at NoProviderError.BaseExc…_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:259:44)", _context: DebugContext, _wrapperStack: "Error: Error in :0:0↵    at ViewWrappedException.W…st:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:322:35)"}consoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0(…)
```

I really have no clue what can cause this, why, and how.

Hope someone can help with this,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can occur because you forgot register **the provider** in your main component.

So, you must import the ROUTER_PROVIDER and after you must register it in your component.

```
import { Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router';
... other imports

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
```

Is very important the array **providers** from @Component.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue when changing to the new router system. In the file where I bootstraped the application, I didn't call the right ROUTER_PROVIDER.
It called

```
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
```

instead of

```
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router';
```

There's so much lines to change, no wonder I skipped one.